# Keep Div Centered

Tags: html, css

How do I make this div stay in the middle of the page. Also how do I change the size of the div?

Html:

```
   <div id="Text">
   <p id="InsideT">
   Hello
   </p>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #Text{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
  right: 320px;
  background: white;
```

Comment: The code you have will work(although some of those CSS rules are unnecessary), what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 4):

Use absolute positioning, and a transform to centre the `div`. The dimensions will then not matter, until the window size is smaller than the `div`.

```css
.centred {
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centred">I am in the centre of the page</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are **already** aligning the `<div>` horizontally with `margin: 0 auto`. Automatic margins centralise a `<div>` because it is a **[block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)**. However, you are applying a number of additional sections of code that break this alignment, such as `position: absolute`, `right: 320px`, `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`.

Horizontal centering can be achieved with simply `margin: 0 auto` and `text-align: center`:

```css
#Text {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="Text">
  <p id="InsideT">
    Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

**Vertical** centering is a little more complicated, and it's easiest to achieve both horizontal and vertical centering with [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), utilising the `display: flex`, `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` property values. Note that you'll also need to specify a `height` property:

```css
#Text {
  height: 180px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Text">
  <p id="InsideT">
    Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You put position absolute which took the div out of it's DOM structure.I removed it and it fixed the issue.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Text">
   <p id="InsideT">
     Hello
   </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #Text {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

```
position: fixed;
```

You can use

```
top: ;
bottom: ;
right: ;
left: ;
```

to move it around and try to center it. The fixed position will keep the div in place, even when you scroll down.

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are meaning the actual X,Y center of the page this will work.

```
#Text{
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  margin: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use position absolute in positioning the element to the center of the page. Use `transform` property in CSS. See below code:

```css
.centerdiv{
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;   
}
```

```html
<div class="centerdiv">centered element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    .card-wrapper {
      min-height: 100vh;
      background: url("https://flevix.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Live-Background-1.svg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .centered-item {
      padding: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="centered-item">
        <p>This will be at the center</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```